# filtering a Drupal View with ORed criteria

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

I'm attempting to present a Drupal View that shows nodes in which the user's e-mail address shows up in one of two CCK text fields. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to be possible using the stock version of Drupal's Views module - there doesn't appear to be a way to combine filtering criteria (except ANDing them), nor does their appear to be a way to do the custom logic for the filter's setting...

Is there a simple way of directly injecting additional information into a specific View's `WHERE` clause? If not, can it be done in another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [views_or](http://drupal.org/project/views%5For) module. It's still in dev but looks promising.

The other option is using `hook_views_query_alter` with $query->add_where() you should be able to add an or clause. You can also use it to add your aditional `WHERE` clause that you asked for.