# View content in blocks depending on selected language

Tags: drupal, translation, drupal-blocks

How can i display content nodes in blocks depending on the selected language by the user?

I already know how to do it for 'normal' nodes, just not in blocks.

Edit: I tried to do this with views. Filtering on a node and content translation: language. The problem is, i don't know how to filter two id's (of the nodes), just one.

Comment: "The problem is, i don't know how to filter two id's (of the nodes), just one." -- what you you mean by this. Can you please explain it again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have created the nodes after each other, you can do it pretty easily, since you can query for a range of node ids.

The views UI doesn't support making OR in where clauses, so it's not easy to make a query that looks like this.

```
SELECT nid FROM {nodes} WHERE nid = 5 OR nid = 10 OR nid = 17;
```

Making OR is views have been asked a few times here, I've answer it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2299154/filtering-a-drupal-view-with-ored-criteria).